# How do I display multiple UIWebViews on a single UIViewController with local files?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to show multiple `UIWebView`'s on a single `UIViewController`, each should show a single HTML file.

In my camView.h file, I've got the following code:

```
@interface camView : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *cam01_valk01;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *cam02_valk02;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *cam03_valk03;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *cam04_tunnel;
```

and in my camView.m file:

```
@interface camView ()

@end

@implementation camView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam1_valk01" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_cam01_valk01 loadRequest:request];

    NSString [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam2_valk02" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_cam02_valk02 loadRequest:request];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam3_valk03" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_cam03_valk03 loadRequest:request];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam4_tunnel" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_cam04_tunnel loadRequest:request];

}
```

Now the issue is that the first `UIWebview` is displaying the HTML content, but all the next ones are getting the error message

1. "redefinition of 'path'"
2. "redefinition of 'url'"
3. "redefinition of 'request'"

I can also clearly see that I'm defining the same thing 4 times, but removing those definitions will completely wreck the code. My experience with xcode is very low, so I don't actually know how to solve it. Please write in depth what the correct solution to showing multiple `UIWebview`'s is.

Comment: so simple man you are giving same name to all objects. dont do that give different names to it

Comment: what is the problem if you are giving different names to it?

Comment: @MohitPopat, I don't really understand your comment. If you got a better solution than Bullet Raja, please explain with code. :) Again, I'm relatively new to xcode, so excuse me for not knowing how to assign (what to adjust) all of that code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface camView ()

@end

@implementation camView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam1_valk01" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_cam01_valk01 loadRequest:request];

        NSString * pathSec = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam2_valk02" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *urlSecond = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathSec];
        NSURLRequest *requestSecond = [NSURLRequest urlSecond];
        [_cam02_valk02 loadRequest:requestSecond];

        NSString *pathThird = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam3_valk03" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *urlThird = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathThird];
        NSURLRequest *requestThird = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlThird];
        [_cam03_valk03 loadRequest:requestThird];

        NSString *pathFour = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cam4_tunnel" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *urlFour = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFour];
        NSURLRequest *requestFour = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlFour];
        [_cam04_tunnel loadRequest:requestFour];

    }
```

Comment: There were a few adjustments I had to make, but it keeps telling me 'expected identifier' on the first line of the second part, (cam2_valk02 line)

Comment: I adjusted your code; you missed a few characters :) - With that slight adjustment, it's working! :)

Comment: Thanks for upvoting it but you can also accept it so that other can see this question on high priority by clicking check sign.